# Finding $\int ^\pi_{-\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, orthogonality

> Find $$\int ^\pi_{-\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)dx$$

I used the product identity and got:

$\displaystyle \int ^\pi_{-\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)dx = -\frac{\cos((n+m){\cdot}x)}{2{\cdot}(n+m)}-\frac{\cos((n-m){\cdot}x)}{2{\cdot}(n-m)} \Bigg | ^{\pi}_{-\pi}=\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{n+m}-\frac 1 {n-m}\right)$

Since $\cos(c\pi)=\cos(-k\pi)=-1$ but the answer is supposed to be zero, so what did I do wrong? the integral is correct as you can see [here](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sin%28nx%29cos%28mx%29).

Comment: The mistake is in the evaluation at $\pi$ and $-\pi$. Assuming $n\neq m$ you have to get the same values, since $\cos(ax)$, for $a\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, is a periodic function with period $\frac{2\pi}{|a|}$.

Comment: Isn't assuming $m=n$ losses the generality? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: In fact the answer just depends on $m$ and $n$ being equal or not. It is the orthogonality condition of the usual base of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: There is no way for the answer to be zero if $m=n$ because you are integrating a nonnegative continuous function which is not identically zero.

Comment: An obvious but probably dead-end straightforward approach would be to try to make use of [trig identities for multiple angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what is the usual $L^2$ base?

Comment: @Vlad the problem isn't finding the integral and I used this identity to find it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: $\cos(-k\pi)=-1$?  No, when $k$ is even this is $1$ not $-1$.  So observe that the two integers $n+m$ and $n-m$ are either both even or both odd.

Comment: @GEdgar oh right... so it does become zero when calculating it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are integrating an odd continuous function over $[-\pi,\pi]$. Hence, the integral must be $0$.

**Added**

Your mistake was probably here

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)\cos(nx)\,dx=\left[-{\cos((n+m)x)\over 2(n+m)}-{\cos((m-n)x)\over 2(n-m)}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi=\\=-{\cos((n+m)\pi)\over 2(n+m)}-{\cos((m-n)\pi)\over 2(n-m)}+{\cos(-(n+m)\pi)\over 2(n+m)}+{\cos(-(m-n)\pi)\over 2(n-m)}=0$$

And the case $n=m$ must be done on itself, but I leave it to you.

Comment: But why it doesn't become zero when trying to place $\pi,-\pi$ in the integral result?

Comment: I've edited, see if it's ok. @kuhaku

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply plug $\pi$ and $-\pi$ into the result and evaluate without expanding the sum of cosine.

\begin{align}
\frac{-\cos((n+m)x)}{2(n+m)} &- \frac{\cos((n-m)x)}{2(n-m)} \\
\frac{-\cos(nx+mx)}{2(n+m)} &- \frac{\cos(nx-mx)}{2(n-m)} \\
\frac{-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{2(n+m)} &- \frac{\cos(nx)\cos(-mx) -\sin(-nx)\sin(-mx)}{2(n-m)} \\
\frac{-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{2(n+m)} &- \frac{-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{2(n-m)}
\end{align}
Finding common denominators, we get,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{[m-n][-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)]}{2(n+m)(n-m)} \\ 
&- \frac{[n+m][-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)]}{2(n+m)(n-m)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Factoring out $u = \dfrac{-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{2(n+m)(n-m)}$ we find
\begin{align}
(n-m)u &- (n+m)u \\
&-2mu
\end{align}

So then we know $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\cos(mx)\;\mathrm{d}x = \left.-2mu\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}$ where $u = \dfrac{-\cos(nx)\cos(mx) + \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{2(n+m)(n-m)}$

So,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\cos(mx)\;\mathrm{d}x &= \left.m\frac{\cos(nx)\cos(mx) - \sin(nx)\sin(mx)}{(n+m)(n-m)}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\
&= \frac{m}{(n+m)(n-m)}\bigg[\cos(n\pi)\cos(m\pi) - \sin(n\pi)\sin(m\pi)\\
&- \cos(-n\pi)\cos(-m\pi) - \sin(-n\pi)\sin(-m\pi)\bigg] \\
&= \frac{m}{(n+m)(n-m)}\bigg[\cos(n\pi)\cos(m\pi) - \sin(n\pi)\sin(m\pi)\\
&- \cos(n\pi)\cos(m\pi) - \sin(n\pi)\sin(m\pi)\bigg] \\
&= \frac{-m}{(n+m)(n-m)}\bigg[2\sin(n\pi)\sin(m\pi)\bigg] \\
&= \frac{-m}{(n+m)(n-m)}\bigg[\cos\big((n\pi-m\pi)\big) - \cos\big((n\pi+m\pi\big)\bigg] \\
&= \frac{-m}{(n+m)(n-m)}\bigg[\cos\big((n-m)\pi)\big) - \cos\big((n+m)\pi\big)\bigg)]
\end{align}
Notice $n+m$ and $n-m$ are either both even or both odd, since they are integers. Since cosine of an even number times $\pi$ is always 1 and cosine of an odd number times $\pi$ is always -1, we will always have $\cos\big((n+m)\pi\big) - \cos(\big((n-m)\pi\big) = 0$. We could also note that since $\sin(n\pi) = 0$ for all $n$, we know that the line before this is also 0, without using the product to sum identity. Thus the integral evaluates to $0$ for $n \neq m$. We know that $n\neq m$ because otherwise the $n-m$ in the denominator would be 0 and then the value would be undefined.

Comment: Actually, he can and he ought to plug in $\pm\pi$ without expanding the sum, because $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in another way to prove the more general orthogonality relation:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{L}\int^{L}_{-L}\cos \left(n\frac{\pi}{L}t\right) \sin\left(m\frac{\pi}{L}t\right)\mathrm{d}t=0,
\end{equation*}

try using the formulae:

\begin{equation*}
\cos(at)=\frac{e^{iat}+e^{-iat}}{2},~\sin(at)=\frac{e^{iat}-e^{iat}}{2i}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: What is $\frac \pi L$ and $L$?

Comment: $L=\pi$ in your case, so $\pi/L = 1$.